# Keep div follow cursor in specific div parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

How can i make a popup follow cursor in its parent div (`$(this)`) ?
I tried this, but the popin does not follow the cursor, every time its position changes when i hover an element.

```
const $divs = $(".domtom-container .svg-container");
let dept = {}, total = {};
$divs.each(function (i) {
    var popup_topo = $("<div class='popup_topo'>" + dept + "<br/>" + total + " parrainages</div>");
    
    $(this).on('mousemove', function (event) {
     const x = event.clientX;
      const y = event.clientY;

      $(this).append(popup_topo);
      popup_topo.css({
        top: `${y}px`,
        lef: `${x}px`,
      });
    }).on('mouseleave', function (event) {
      popup_topo.remove();
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="domtom-container">
   <div class="svg-container svg-topo">
      <svg width="36" height="43"> </svg>
      <p> Nouvelle-Calédonie </p>
   </div>
   <div class="svg-container svg-topo">
      <svg width="52" height="65"></svg>
      <p> Guyane </p>
   </div>
   <div class="svg-container svg-topo">
      <svg width="68" height="44"> </svg>

      <p> Polynésie française </p>
   </div>
   <div class="svg-container">
      <svg width="48" height="37"> </svg>
      <p> Parlement européen </p>
   </div>
   <div class="svg-container svg-topo">
      <svg width="51" height="45"></svg>
      <p> La Réunion </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.svg-container {
        &.svg-topo {
            position: relative;
            .popup_topo {
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 1.4rem;
                background-color: #1E2382;
                color: #FFF;
                padding: .5rem;
                transition: .1s;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                z-index: 999;
            }
            &:hover {
                svg {
                    path {
                        fill : #1E2382!important;
                    }
                }
            }
            svg {
                min-height: 5rem;
            }
        }
    }
```

I think the calculation of the position of the popin is badly done but i don't know how.
PLease check the screenshot (GIF) below

PS : im using Datamaps plugin : https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/README.md#using-custom-maps

[image]

Comment: What is the CSS for `popup_topo`? what element is `$(this)`?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. Also, your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Rojo, it's not easy to put all the code since it comes from a plugin ,  did my best  (post updated)  :/

Comment: You are appending the div to the svg-topo divs, but the position is based off the page, not the svg-topo div. You either need to append the pop up to the div or adjust the x/y position so it is based off the hover element and not the top eft of the page.

Comment: If you are using a plugin, you should include the name of that plugin and the source code (as a link)

Comment: @epascarello but with ` $(this).append(popup_topo);` i already added the popin to the div ($this)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening cuz the clientX and ClientY are calculated based on the position of the SVG element. What you want is the absolute point on the screen.

consider,

```
const $divs = $(".domtom-container .svg-container");
const x = $divs.offset().left - event.clientX;
const y = $divs.offset().top - event.clientY;

now pass this value to the css.
 popup_topo.css({
        top: `${y}px`,
        lef: `${x}px`,
      });
```

Comment: that's not working, i have the popin in the DOM but i don't see it beside.